# Builder for Linked list with two types

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Here is what I am trying to solve:

I need to model a `Route` from `Location` A to Z via many other locations B, C...Y. A location is connected only to the next location via exactly one `Road`.

So I have two entities: `Location` and `Road`

```
Location implements RouteElement{
   String name;
   BigDecimal lat;
   BigDecimal long;

   RouteElement nextElement; // optional
}

Road implements RoutElement{
   Length howLong;
   Boolean hasTolls;

   RouteElement nextElement; // mandatory
}
```

And finally,

```
Route {
   // some properties
   RouteElement startingElement;
}
```

Now, All these entities are `immutable`, so once a nextElement is set to null in Location, it can not be "set" unless I create a copy on the first object.

So, I was thinking if I can come up with a `RouteBuilder` to build a Route gracefully!

Could someone please suggest how to write a Builder for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe u can provide both `RouteBuilder` and `LocationBuilder`/`RoadBuilder`. That is , `Location`/`Road` is `immutable` but `LocationBuilder`/`RoadBuilder` is `mutable`.
In this builder pattern, you're actually build `Route` first then set `nextElement` finally build `immutable` node.
Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm sure there is a nice solution for this. However, you should elaborate and "clean up" the question a bit. Preferably with compileable classes, showing the constructors (!). One could probably also solve this with a *single* builder, which only has a method like `append(RoadData a, LocationData b)`. The tricky part might be that the whole "chain" (consisting of `Location`-`Road`-`Location`-`Road`...) can only be built when the *last* location is known.